# AWS Lambda, An error occurred (InvalidToken) when calling the PutObject operation: The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, lambda

I made a Django application and tried to deploy it using Zappa and AWS Lambda.

My deployment was successfully deployed but, the image was not uploaded to AWS S3 to invoke the API.

### This is my cloudwatch error log

```
[ERROR] 2022-04-22T08:35:19.84Z cbf18c70-f478-4363-8f5a-0777c76564e9    Internal Server Error: /production/v1/ReviewCamping/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/var/task/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/var/task/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/var/task/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/var/task/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/var/task/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 19, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "/var/task/service/views/v1/camping.py", line 80, in perform_create
    serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
  File "/var/task/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 212, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "/var/task/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 962, in create
    instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)
  File "/var/task/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/django/db/models/query.py", line 514, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/var/task/django/db/models/base.py", line 806, in save
    self.save_base(
  File "/var/task/django/db/models/base.py", line 857, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/var/task/django/db/models/base.py", line 1000, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(
  File "/var/task/django/db/models/base.py", line 1041, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "/var/task/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/task/django/db/models/query.py", line 1434, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/var/task/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1620, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "/var/task/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1547, in as_sql
    value_rows = [
  File "/var/task/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1548, in <listcomp>
    [
  File "/var/task/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1549, in <listcomp>
    self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj))
  File "/var/task/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1497, in pre_save_val
    return field.pre_save(obj, add=True)
  File "/var/task/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 316, in pre_save
    file.save(file.name, file.file, save=False)
  File "/var/task/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 92, in save
    self.name = self.storage.save(name, content, max_length=self.field.max_length)
  File "/var/task/django/core/files/storage.py", line 57, in save
    name = self._save(name, content)
  File "/var/task/storages/backends/s3boto3.py", line 459, in _save
    obj.upload_fileobj(content, ExtraArgs=params)
  File "/var/runtime/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 620, in object_upload_fileobj
    return self.meta.client.upload_fileobj(
  File "/var/runtime/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 540, in upload_fileobj
    return future.result()
  File "/var/runtime/s3transfer/futures.py", line 103, in result
    return self._coordinator.result()
  File "/var/runtime/s3transfer/futures.py", line 266, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/var/runtime/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 139, in __call__
    return self._execute_main(kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 162, in _execute_main
    return_value = self._main(**kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/s3transfer/upload.py", line 758, in _main
    client.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key, Body=body, **extra_args)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 391, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 719, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidToken) when calling the PutObject operation: The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid.
```

All Access Keys have been verified correctly and work correctly in the Local environment.
How can I solve this?

### My settings.py

```py
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = env("AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = env("AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = "ap-northeast-2"
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = env("AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME")
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = (
    f"{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.{AWS_S3_REGION_NAME}.amazonaws.com"
)
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = "public-read"
```

Comment: Are the supplied credentials associated with an IAM User or an IAM Role? If the latter, you need a [session token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_use-resources.html#using-temp-creds-sdk).

Comment: @jarmod I used IAM User

Answer (score 0):

this issue resolve in this [article](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/606)

```py
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage


class SecurityTokenWorkaroundS3Boto3Storage(S3Boto3Storage):
    def _get_security_token(self):
        return None

class MediaStorage(SecurityTokenWorkaroundS3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.MEDIAFILES_LOCATION

class StaticStorage(SecurityTokenWorkaroundS3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION
```